# Convert &#XXXX; character to UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, android, unicode, utf-8

I am using GCM service to get push `notification`. English messages are receive as the are.

But when I send Arabic messages  like `انا يمني`  I receive something like this

> `&#1575;&#1606;&#1575; &#1610;&#1605;&#1606;&#1610`

which is Arabic Unicode as I know.I tried to decode that message as the following but nothing has changed on my logcat.

```
    sendNotification("News: " + extras.get("message"));
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        try {
            String msgDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(msg, "UTF-8");
            Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msgDecoded);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Edite**
I also tried this way

```
    try {
        String msgDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(intent.getStringExtra("message"),"UTF-8");
        sendNotification(msgDecoded);
        Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + msgDecoded);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Same resault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String with `&#xxxx;` are `Cp1256` encoding .This below function decode Strings with `Cp1256` encoding

```
 private String convertToArabic(String value) {
        if(value.indexOf("&#")==-1)
            return value;

        String newString ="";
        value = value.replaceAll("&#","");
        String[] characters = value.split(";");
        for(int i=0; i<characters.length; i++){
            if(characters[i].startsWith(" "))
                newString +=" ";

            if(characters[i].trim().length()!=4)
                newString += characters[i].trim();
            else
                newString +=(char)Integer.valueOf(characters[i].trim()).intValue()+"";
        }

        return newString;
    }
```

Test this function:

```
    System.out.println(convertToArabic("&#1575;&#1606;&#1575; &#1610;&#1605;&#1606;&#1610"));
```

**Output:**

```
I/System.out﹕ انا یمني
```

Comment: That's almost right! one problem is the first letter of the second word gets eaten like you mention in your answer انا مني instead of انا يمني. how can I fix it?

Comment: @sabsab check my answer again i change `else if` to `if`

Comment: Now everything works perfect! thank you. Just wandering ... is it better practice to encode the string into Unicode in server-side?

Comment: @sabsab yes of course . it's better to change your characters to \uxxxx encoding because android can easily change them to persian , arabic ,... .